# Is it possible to enter debug mode for android when running junit test?

Tags: android, junit, tdd, android-testing

Usually i run a junit test using `adb shell am instrument -w com.android.contacts.tests/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner`. And it actually works, it will run all my tests.

But when i make a breakpoints and wish to enter debug mode when running junit, it failed. The way i make breakpoints works when i debug normal android app.

So i searched web, and try something like `adb shell am instrument -e debug true -e class com.android.contacts.AndroidUtilsTest -w com.android.contacts.tests/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner`, but still without luck. How do yours solve this problem? I not just want to debug the junit class, but also the code in normal project.

Answer (score 7):

I guess you are trying to debug your tests using Eclipse. If this is the case you can just select you test project, right click, ***Debug As... -> Android JUNit test*** and the execution will stop at the breakpoints you set in your tests or in your code.

Comment: Actually, i do all these job in command line. Maybe in eclipse, your method will work.

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer just now. It will block when i start instrument since it is waiting for me to set a breakpoint. So After i make a breakpoint, then the junit start to run. So the sequence of debug a android junit project is :

1. start instrument with debug set true.
2. make a break point using command line or eclipse.
3. the instrument will start to run automatically.

Comment: In case of JetBrains Idea: 1. start instrument with debug set true. 2. Attach debugger to process of your application 3. Testing will start

Comment: What do you mean "debug set true"?  Where is this setting?

Answer (score 0):

To Debug Android JUnit test don't forget to put `debuggable=true` in the testable project.

Comment: Actually, don't do that. The build tools will do it for you.