# Calabash-android: attach to running app

Tags: android, cucumber, calabash, calabash-android, android-instrumentation

I have calabash-android set up working perfectly with a default scenario (using `cucumber` to run tests or `calabash-android console` to enter REPL mode).

However, under some scenarios, it turns out to be pretty useful to be able to attach to an app that's already running. For instance, I would start an app in debug mode and start the tests to be able to set breakpoints and check why certain features don't work as expected in my scenarios.

When it comes to Calabash on iOS, this task is really straightforward: no additional preparation needed as the app starts with a test server bundled in and I can attach calabash to it at any time. However, Calabash Android seems to be force-quitting the app every time I try to start calabash having the app running.

Is there any way around it?

**EDIT** 
Looks like the below answers didn't help much, but I still hope someone (calabash devs, where are you?) will stumble upon this one day. I have spent some time discovering the issue myself, and that's what the specific issue is:

1. Start the app in Debug mode (using Xamarin, for instance)
2. Start `calabash-android console PATH_TO_APK`
3. Try issuing any commands (e.g. `query("*")`) – it fails with a message KeepAliveDisconnected
4. Try running start_test_server_in_background – the app is killed and debug session is terminated

Digging deeper into details, I found out that start_test_server_in_background in fact runs `shell am instrument` with `sh.calaba.instrumentationbackend.CalabashInstrumentationTestRunner` being instrumentation backend and a bunch of other flags describing which app to instrument, what port to use etc.

Thus being said, the following would help a lot: **is it possible for shell am instrument to attach to a running app**?

Comment: Calabash has to start the app via the instrumentation command, in order to have its server running with privileges that let it query and control the app. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10942049/is-it-possible-to-enter-debug-mode-for-android-when-running-junit-test suggests you might add -e 'debug true' to Calabash's instrumentation command, then use the 'attach to running process' button (to the side of the debug icon in Android Studio) Make sure your app's manifest is set debuggable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question, and the simple answer is:

> No

At least not on Android (I cannot attest to iOS). Why? Calabash has to establish hooks on the app you want to run on before you can run any tests on the app. This is due to a mixture of reasons regarding the Android stack.

The first reason is security. Android locks down apps in the installation phase based on the permissions set for it. Because of this design, Calabash (or any other app-process-interfering script) will not be able to execute in the middle of an app process. As you have found out, you can still run Calabash tests together with the start of the app as Android will validate Calabash for this purpose.

The second reason is architecture. Android is designed as layers of processes and views. What you are trying to do will probably interfere with more than one process on a variety of levels.

The best you can do is start Calabash for an App without reinstalling it, but that is the most Android will allow you to do.

Finally, I apologize if this answer does not delve into the very technical details, these were the answers given to me during a particular Hackathon as I struggled with a similar issue.

Comment: Sounds reasonable, but how does debugging of unit tests work then? They, in fact, use the same instrumentation runner as Calabash does, but we can definitely debug the app as it runs through unit tests. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

I've just successfully done it. There wasn't much to it - I just paused the Calabash tests at the point of failure with an 'After' hook that pauses Ruby (actually, it uses IRB, but that's incidental):

```
After do |scenario|
  if scenario.failed? && scenario.source_tag_names.include?('@wip') && PLATFORM == ANDROID
    require 'irb'
    require 'irb/completion'
    ARGV.clear
    IRB.start
  end
end
```

then fired up Android Studio, clicked on the 'Attach debugger to Android process' button to the right of the normal debug icon in the toolbar, clicked the 'Can't connect to adb' pop-up to tell it to try again (without killing/restarting adb myself), clicked the process it offered me, and... it connected happily. I successfully set a breakpoint and hit it, and executed query("*") in the console both before and after.

I haven't had to change the Calabash instrument command to add -e 'debug true' or anything.

The only thing that went wrong was that Android Studio took out the adb server when I closed it, but I think that's a known bug^H^H^Hfeature.

Perhaps if you create a 'And Cucumber waits for a keypress' step that waits for you to hit the host computer's keyboard, so you can attach Android Studio to the phone's process and set your breakpoints before resuming. Obviously though - breakpoints are going to mess up any timing in the script.

Answer (score 0):

Calabash-Android stops any test-server, and the app under test, when you start a new server on the same port.

If you wish to attach a console to a running test, simply open a console (`bundle exec calabash console ..`) and issue your gestures and queries, without starting the app using `start_test_server_in_background`. A common pattern is to use the gem pry, with the method `binding.pry` to pause the test, and launch a console.

Notice that the generated Calabash-Android cucumber skeleton will run `shutdown_test_server` automatically when a cucumber scenario fails or ends. You can remove that call and attach a console.

Comment: As I've mentioned, it's fine on iOS, but on Android it doesn't seem to be working – please note I would like to ATTACH to an app that's running already as I want to debug the app, not the tests. And as the app has been started by someone else, TestInstrumentation is not launched and therefore the console cannot connect to the app.

Comment: Alright, as @bernlim said, Calabash-Android does not currently support attaching to an app that has not been started by the Calabash framework. What is the usecase, and what are you trying to solve?

Comment: Plain simple in fact: I want to debug the tests. Say, I notice a scenario failing and I want to debug the app as it runs through the scenario – this seems to be a time saver as some scenarios might be quite complex and involve seed data pre-configured on the server, which means reproducing the issue manually is a bit painful